# I need to create a program that will add, remove, list, save, and sort students in a created Student, Undergrad, and Graduate classes

Tags: java

I have three different classes, one for grad students, undergrads, and then a general student class, I need to figure out how to add students to an array list, from the main method. I can't figure out how to add a first name because it is private, and it needs to stay private.

```
package enrollmentdatabase;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class EnrollmentDataBase {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
    String option = optionChoise(input);
    String option1 = "ADD";//ADD option
    String option2 = "REMOVE";//REMOVE OPTION
    String option3 = "LIST";//LIST OPTION
    String option4 = "SAVE";//SAVE OPTION
    String option5 = "SORT";//SORT OPTION
    ArrayList studentList = new ArrayList();

}//end of main method
public static String optionChoise(Scanner input){
    String opt1 = "ADD";//ADD option
    String opt2 = "REMOVE";//REMOVE OPTION
    String opt3 = "LIST";//LIST OPTION
    String opt4 = "SAVE";//SAVE OPTION
    String opt5 = "SORT";//SORT OPTION
    System.out.println("Enter what you want to do(ADD, REMOVE, LIST, SAVE, or SORT): ");
    String opt = input.nextLine();
    if((opt.compareToIgnoreCase(opt1)) !=0 || (opt.compareToIgnoreCase(opt1)) != 0 || (opt.compareToIgnoreCase(opt1)) !=0
            || (opt.compareToIgnoreCase(opt1)) !=0 || (opt.compareToIgnoreCase(opt1)) !=0){//enter this if conditional in order to establish that the input is valid
        System.out.println("This is not a valid input, please enter in what you want to do: ");
        opt = input.nextLine();
    }//end of if conditional
    return opt;
}//end of option method
public static ArrayList addList(ArrayList studentList, Scanner input){
    System.out.println("Enter the Student's first name: ");
    String nameFirst= input.nextLine();
    Student student1 = new Student();
    student1.firstName = nameFirst;
    System.out.println("Enter the Student's last name: ");
    System.out.println("Enter the Student's UID: ");
    System.out.println("Enter the Student's status: ");
    System.out.println("Enter YES for having a thesis option, else NO: ");
    System.out.println("Enter Masters for Master Studies of PHD for PHD studies: ");
    System.out.println("Enter the name of the major professor: ");
    System.out.println("Enter the student class standing: ");
    System.out.println("Enter the Student's major: ");
    System.out.println("Enter the student's overall GPA: ");
    System.out.println("Enter the student's major GPA: ");
}//end of addList method
}//end of class
```

Comment: holy ...? you are inventing the database?

Comment: @BlueBullet.. I would say "manufacturing the database".. ;)

Comment: Read good Java books, and write basic codes, before diving into ArrayList directly. You can start with [**this oracle tutorial**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classes.html). Because, even if someone give you a way for this, it will not be benefitial for you.

Comment: Can't distinguish modifiers?

Answer (score 1):

> I can't figure out how to add a first name because it is private,

have **public getter** and **public setter** methods for that **private data** and access it through them.

For instance:

```
    class Student {
    private String fName;
    public void setFname(String fName){
    this.fName = fName;
    }
    public String getFName(){
    return fname;
    }
    }
class AnotherClass {
public static void main(String...args){
student s = new Student();
System.out.println(s.getFName());//to access fName(which is private) in class Student.
}
```

}